# Heroku deployment of play 2.1 application very slow (region eu)

Tags: heroku, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

The deployment of my play 2.1 application is very slow since several weeks. In fact it is randomly so slow that the build times out (15 minutes time limit).

I already tried to use a custom buildpack, with few to no effect.

When I do the build locally as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/debugging-java-scala-builds) it takes appr. 10 minutes, but most of the time is spend in retrieval of the dependent artifacts. When i have a look at the build on Heroku, the retrieval doesn't need much time and thus the retrieval seems not to be the problem.

About the build: [info] Compiling 83 Scala sources and 3 Java sources.

It looks like the generation and packaging of sources and docs (never used in prod) seem to take a significant amount of time.

Is there any way to reduce the build time significantly, e.g. by shutting of the generation of docs?

Comment: I have the same problem and am hoping to get some support from Heroku.

Comment: Same here. Going to look at building elsewhere and pushing the slug to Heroku. See: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially reduce the time of compilation by reducing what is included in the compilation of your application.  You can tell the Heroku slug compiler to exclude things like docs and sources from the application slug it creates.

Heroku uses a file called .slugignore which is the same concept as the .gitignore file.  Details of the .slugignore file are covered in the Slug Compiler article on Heroku Dev Center:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

If you are unsure as to what is actually making up your deployment, you can connect via secure shell to your running Heroku application using the command

```
heroku run bash
```

Then you can navigate around your application deployment files and folders to see if there is anything else you can remove.  The Heroku Scala build pack should have removed things like the ivy cache.

Comment: thanks. already tried that. but the effect is little to nothing at all. strange thing is also the variation in the build time. from all together 5 minutes till timeout after 30 minutes (i got a special flag by heroku) everything occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, I run into the same problem. Not 100% sure, but I suspect it's one of the sbt dependencies checking causing the problem. For me, the symptom is after the 'OpenJDK install ... done' message, the next one waits for 3-5 minutes to come.